# How to combine array of numbers so resulting number is as large as possible in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of positive integers as an input in javascript. Output should be the greatest possible integer created out of combined array elements in input. Examples:

1. input: `[80,35,2,9,45,8]` output: `988045352`
2. input: `[509,7,49,21,527,2,742]` output: `774252750949221`

I think I know the logic that could be used but fails to pull it off...

I guess that two array elements next to each other should be concatenated in both directions and this values to be compared, which one is the bigger and then use this logic to sort all array elements. However, I can't do it in javaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you at least show us the code that creates the array?

Comment: You need to define "combine" better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the string is smaller than the switched value.

```js
function sort(a, b) {
    return ('' + b + a) - ('' + a + b);
}

console.log(+[509, 7, 49, 21, 527, 2, 742].sort(sort).join(''));
console.log(+[80, 35, 2, 9, 45, 8].sort(sort).join(''));
```

Comment: Hi Nina, this code works but I dont get integer on the end. When I try to convert string to integer with Number() or parceInt() it wont work. Do you know why?  Thank you!

Comment: btw, `parseInt`. you could add an unary `+` in front of the result string, like above. This converts implicit to a number.

Answer (score 6):

Do this:

```
a = [80,35,2,9,45,8];

result = a.sort((x,y)=> ""+x+y < ""+y+x);
```

result:

```
[ 9, 8, 80, 45, 35, 2 ]
```

And for the second one the result is:

```
[ 7, 742, 527, 509, 49, 2, 21 ]
```

If you want a single number use `.join("")` after the sort.

Answer (score 0):

After converting integers to Strings, compare their unions:

```js
function Comparator(a, b) {
  var s1 = a.toString();
  var s2 = b.toString();
  return (s2+s1).localeCompare(s1+s2);
}

var myArray = [509, 7, 49, 21, 527, 2, 742].sort(Comparator);
console.log(myArray.join(''));
```